# Need advice on nested Promises.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Playing around with modern JS and got stuck a little with the following.

Consider having an ExtSystem accessible via some HTTP API and local Mongo instance. They both contain objects with `name` and `id`.

For Mongo I'm using `mongoose` with `ObjectSchema` model (`{_id, sourceId, name, internalParam}`) where `sourceId` equal to `id` from ExtSystem and `internalParam` exists only in my app. For ExtSystem there is 2 methods returning `request.js` Promise:

- ExtSystem.all returns array of ids `[id, id, id]`
- ExtSystem.get returns object itself `{id, name}`

There is also a global function `errHandler` which can handle errors from both `request.js` and `mongoose` Promises. The goal to achieve is to sync Mongo with ExtSystem: update all objects from ExtSystem in Mongo and delete no longer present in ExtSystem ones from Mongo.

What I came up with:

```
ExtSystem.all().then(body => { 
    let basket = []; // will store all promises for both ExtSystem and Mongo requests
    basket.push(...body.map(o => ExtSystem.get(o.id));
    basket.push(ObjectSchema.find({}, 'sourceId'));

    Promise.all(basket).then(basketDoc => {
        let mongoObjects = {}, extObjects = {};
        basketDoc.pop().forEach(o => mongoObjects[o.sourceId] = o._id); // Mongo retuns array of {_id, sourceId } objects
        basketDoc.forEach(o => { // ExtSystem returns array of {id, name} objects
            extObjects[o.id] = {
                sourceId: o.id,
                name: o.name
            }
        });

        let esSet = new Set(Object.keys(extObjects));
        let mongoDeleteIds = Object.keys(mongoObjects).filter(oId => !esSet.has(oId)); // Set.has is faster than Array.indexOf

        let syncPromises = [];
        syncPromises.push(...Object.keys(extObjects).map(oId => ObjectSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceId: extObjects[oId].sourceId }, extObjects[oId], { upsert: true, new: true })));
        syncPromises.push(...mongoDeleteIds.map(oId => ObjectSchema.remove({_id: oId})));

        Promise.all(syncPromises).then(_ => { // I don't need results, only the moment when sync is complete
            ObjectSchema.find().then(doc => { // return actual objects from Mongo
                someBusinessLogic(doc);
            }).catch(errHandler);
        }).catch(errHandler);
    }).catch(errHandler);
}).catch(errHandler);
```

So I still have 4 nested Promise resolves and probably missing something. Is there a best way to achieve this with less complex code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are designed to get rid of the *pyramids of doom*. If you have nested Promises then you are doing it wrong.

Promises allow you to return another promise inside the call in order to chain them. So instead of doing:

```
p1.then(stuff => {
    p2.then(stuff =>{
        ...
    });
});
```

You should do

```
p1
.then(stuff => {
    return p2;
}).then(stuff => {
    return;
});
```

If you have some variables that you need to access in the future promises, you can either include them as another promise, or use [this piece of code](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ssr23mjy/) I created a while ago that create a promise that contains a global reusable object.

```
Promise
.resolve({})           // creates global object for holding values
.then(obj => {
    return pack(obj, taskPromiseA, "a", taskPromiseB, "b");
})
.then(obj => {        // you can access results from A and B here
    return pack(obj, taskPromiseC, "c");
})
.then(console.log);   // you can access them all here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a Promise from a thenable to chain it. Because it can chain, that means all your errors can be propagated to one handler.

Your code could essentially become:

```
ExtSystem.all().then(body => {
    let basket = []; // will store all promises for both ExtSystem and Mongo requests
    basket.push(...body.map(o => ExtSystem.get(o.id));
    basket.push(ObjectSchema.find({}, 'sourceId'));
    return Promise.all(basket);
}).then(basketDoc => {
    let mongoObjects = {}, extObjects = {};
    basketDoc.pop().forEach(o => mongoObjects[o.sourceId] = o._id); // Mongo retuns array of {_id, sourceId } objects
    basketDoc.forEach(o => { // ExtSystem returns array of {id, name} objects
        extObjects[o.id] = {
            sourceId: o.id,
            name: o.name
        }
    });

    let esSet = new Set(Object.keys(extObjects));
    let mongoDeleteIds = Object.keys(mongoObjects).filter(oId => !esSet.has(oId)); // Set.has is faster than Array.indexOf

    let syncPromises = [];
    syncPromises.push(...Object.keys(extObjects).map(oId => ObjectSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceId: extObjects[oId].sourceId }, extObjects[oId], { upsert: true, new: true })));
    syncPromises.push(...mongoDeleteIds.map(oId => ObjectSchema.remove({_id: oId})));
    return Promise.all(syncPromises);
}).then(_ => {
    return ObjectSchema.find();
}).then(doc => {
    return someBusinessLogic(doc);
}).catch(errHandler);
```